# Import data from text, read only

Tags: excel

I have a Python script which continuously writes to a csv file.
I'd like to build an excel file which reads this csv file, and formats it nicely.

I tried to use "Data > From Text", but it turns out that, whenever this sheet then reads the csv file, it doesn't do this in a "read-only" way: the Python script becomes unable to open the csv file in write mode.

None of the dialogue boxes involved mention the possibility of using read-only mode.

Is there a way to accomplish this without resorting to VBA (which I'd really rather not touch)?

Comment: @pnuts What would that accomplish? I'd want the excel file to periodically re-load the csv file, because the contents of the csv file change over time.

Comment: The objective is to have an excel file which can be opened and refreshed at any time without interfering with the process which creates the data that goes into the excel file.

Comment: I use "Get External Data" to read TXT and CSV files into Excel all the time and I've never had this problem.   I just tried to replicate in a dummy file and I was able to edit the CSV, then refresh the data in Excel to bring in my changes.   Have you tried removing the data connection then starting again?    I have had occasionally other bugs and glitches with data connections which were resolved by re-initialising the setup.

Comment: @tjejijyj: To properly replicate the problem, you'd have to try to write to the CSV file *while* Excel is refreshing.